# Create GraphQl Schema from GraphQl query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, schema, apollo

I want to create a GraphQl schema for the following GraphQL query

```
query ($DateFilter: Date!, $oType: String, $voyStat: VoyageVoyageStatusCodeEnum)  {
    imos {
      voyageList (query: {
                    limit: 1
                    where:
                    {
                        or : [
                            {lastUpdateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}},
                            {completeDateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}}
                            ]
                        and : [
                            {oprType: {is : $oType }},
                            {voyageStatusCode: {isNot : $voyStat }}
                            ]
                    }
                })  {
          vesselCode
          lastUpdateGmt
          voyageNo
          voyageStatus
          tradeAreaName
          oprType
          completeDateGmt
          commenceDateGmt
          vessel {
              vesselType
              isActive
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the schema I have written so far

```
#graphql
  scalar Date

  type AristowVessel {
    vesselType: String,
    isActive: Boolean
  }

  type VoyageAristow {
    vesselCode: String
    lastUpdateGmt: String
    voyageNo: Int
    voyageStatus: String
    oprType: String
    tradeAreaName: String
    commenceDateGmt: Date
    completeDateGmt: Date
    vessel: AristowVessel
  }

  type VoyageAristowList {
    voyageList: [VoyageAristow]
  }
  
  type Query {
    imos: VoyageAristowList
  }
```

But this is creating the below query

```
query {
  imos {
    voyageList {
      vesselCode
      lastUpdateGmt
      tradeAreaName
      voyageNo
      voyageStatus
      oprType
      completeDateGmt
      commenceDateGmt
      vessel {
        vesselType
        isActive
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the resolver for the above schema

```
const voyageAristowController = {
    Query: {
      imos: async () => {
        try {
            const voyageData: any = await voyageAristowService.getVoyageData();
            console.log("Voyage Data Response = ",voyageData);
            let vdata:any = [];
            for(let row of voyageData) {
              vdata.push({
                vesselCode: row.vslCode,
                lastUpdateGmt: row.last_update,
                voyageNo: row.voyNum,
                voyageStatus: row.vtype,
                tradeAreaName: row.lob,
                oprType: row.oprType,
                commenceDateGmt: row.commenceGmt,
                completeDateGmt: row.completeGmt,
                vessel: {
                  vesselType: "J32",
                  isActive: true
                }
              });
            }
            return { voyageList: vdata };
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(`Error:  - : ${err}`);
        }
    }
    }
};
```

Up to this, the query is returning the data but now I want to add that query filter part how can I add the below part in my schema and get those values in my resolver function so that I can it in *voyageAristowService.getVoyageData()* to add filter in my mongodb query

```
query: {
                    limit: 1
                    where:
                    {
                        or : [
                            {lastUpdateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}},
                            {completeDateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}}
                            ]
                        and : [
                            {oprType: {is : $oType }},
                            {voyageStatusCode: {isNot : $voyStat }}
                            ]
                    }
                }
```

I have tried writing schema like this but it now working

```
#graphql
  scalar Date

  input DateFilterInput {
    isAfter: Date!
  }

  input OprTypeInput {
    is: String!
  }

  input VoyageStatusCodeInput {
    isNot: String!
  }

  input VoyageQueryWhereInput {
    or: [VoyageQueryWhereInput!]
    and: [VoyageQueryWhereInput!]
    lastUpdateGmt: DateFilterInput
    completeDateGmt: DateFilterInput
    oprType: OprTypeInput
    voyageStatusCode: VoyageStatusCodeInput
  }

  input VoyageQueryInput {
    limit: Int!
    where: VoyageQueryWhereInput!
  }

  type AristowVessel {
    vesselType: String,
    isActive: Boolean
  }

  type VoyageAristow {
    vesselCode: String
    lastUpdateGmt: String
    voyageNo: Int
    voyageStatus: String
    oprType: String
    tradeAreaName: String
    commenceDateGmt: Date
    completeDateGmt: Date
    vessel: AristowVessel
  }

  type VoyageAristowList {
    voyageList(query: VoyageQueryInput): [VoyageAristow]
  }
  
  type Query {
    imos: VoyageAristowList
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

(new type)

```
input VoyageConditionInput {
  lastUpdateGmt: DateFilterInput
  completeDateGmt: DateFilterInput
  oprType: OprTypeInput
  voyageStatusCode: VoyageStatusCodeInput
}
```

then... (modified type)

```
  input VoyageQueryWhereInput {
    or: [VoyageConditionInput]
    and: [VoyageConditionInput]
  }
```

Comment: Yes I can do this modification but how can I get `voyageList(query: VoyageQueryInput)` query parameter vale in my `imos: async ()` function in controller file?